# CakePhp: unable to add row to database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i'm try to add a new row to a table of my database by using CakePhp framework, but something it's not work properly.
This is my add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create(array('type' => 'get'));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');

echo $this->Form->end('Save');
```

This is controller add function:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->Admin->create();
        if ($this->Admin->save($this->request->data)) {
            debug("done");
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Admin Model class:

```
class Admin extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    )
);
```

but new row is never added to my Admins table. Database works fine (i can retrieve all rows inside table).
I'm working on localhost with xampp

Comment: I think your form should be of type `post`

Comment: Ok, it works, but why? Framework admit only POST method for save something on database?

Comment: I must admite that I've never used a from of type `get` before, some I am not sure. Have you debugged your values? I mean `$this->request->data` because in post type forms I use `$this->data`. I don't know what else could be.

Comment: Why a _post_? Because your form _posts_ the data. Did you examine the HTML generated by that view? FYI: Cakephp can handle _posts_ and _gets_.

Comment: @giozh its because cake handles data with post and get requests diffrently check my answer below

Comment: If you would like use GET Method, it should be $this->request->query instead $this->request->data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because your $this->request->data [is not populated with information you sent with your request](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data). Simply CakePHP handles [post](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data) and [get](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters) differently.

> All POST data can be accessed using CakeRequest::$data.

If for some unknown reason you want to send your password with form using 'get' you can access it like this

```
$data['username'] = $this->params['url']['username'];
$data['password'] = $this->params['url']['password'];
```

Also please take a look at [this 'when do you use post, when do you use get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Comment: i know when to use post and when to use get. In this case i've try to use GET intentionally for test purpose (i've try to pass params directly like /admin/add?username=myusername&password=mypassword)